# how to findout which Class/Object is calling current winForm/object in c#

Tags: c#

hey guys, i have 3 winForms named carForm,parForm and updateForm, so there's `updateForm.show()` method in both carForm n parForm, while m in updateForm i want to know which class/form has called updateForm, so that i can update the respected class db. Currently i'm setting up a `public` global `variable` to verify that which form is calling updateForm..but i was thinkin' is there's another way to do this, i guess Reflection can solve this issue, but i'm not able to solve it, here's my code

```
///carForm
public class carForm:Form
{
    Program.globalvariable="CAR";    //global variable
    UpdateFrom updateForm=new UpdateForm();
    updateForm.Show();

}

///parForm
public class parForm:Form
{
     Program.globalvariable="PAR";
     UpdateFrom updateForm=new UpdateForm
     updateForm.Show();

}

///updateForm
public class updateForm:Form
{
    if(Program.globalvariable=="CAR")
       ///code for update CAR db table
    else if(Program.globalvariable=="PAR")
       ///code for update PAR db table

    Type obj = GetType();  //This is what i was tryin' using Reflection but giving error

}
```

so if i get the calling Class/Objects info, i can update respected DB table,

can ne1 know hw to do this with Reflection,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the argument in a constructor of `updateForm`

```
///carForm
public class carForm:Form
{
    UpdateFrom updateForm=new UpdateForm("CAR");
    updateForm.Show();
}

///parForm
public class parForm:Form
{
     UpdateFrom updateForm=new UpdateForm("PAR");
     updateForm.Show();
}

///updateForm
public class updateForm:Form
{
    private readonly string _key;
    public updateForm(string key)
    {
        _key = key;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // check for _key here.
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
If you want to have the actual type you can pass it directly, no need for reflection.

```
///carForm
public class carForm:Form
{
    UpdateFrom updateForm=new UpdateForm(this.GetType());
    updateForm.Show();
}

///parForm
public class parForm:Form
{
     UpdateFrom updateForm=new UpdateForm(this.GetType());
     updateForm.Show();
}

///updateForm
public class updateForm:Form
{
    private readonly Type _type;
    public updateForm(Type type)
    {
        _type = type;
    }

    public void SomeMethod()
    {
        // check for _type here.
    }    
}
```

**Edit 2:**
But in general, passing the type like this smells like bad code. Your control flow will probably end up like a bowl of spaghetti.

If you want the `updateForm` to update some values on the other forms you should

1. Send all relevant information about what questions/titles/etc to show in the `updateForm` in the constructor of the `updateForm`.
2. In the `updateForm`, save relevant "answers" to public properties of `updateForm`
3. Set `DialogResult` in `updateForm` to `OK` or `Cancel` depending on how you exit `updatForm`
4. Call `updateForm` like this: `if (updateForm.ShowDialog == DialogResult.OK) {// read all properties from updateForm}`

Comment: @FosterZ, Why would you use reflection? Do you want to know the type of the caller instead of the string "PAR"/"CAR"? Or do you want to have a reference to the actual form that called updateForm?

Comment: i want to know the properties of the caller and type

Comment: @FosterZ, typically you don't want that. The `updateForm` should be asked for values, not figuring out who asked and what. Se update 2 in my answer.

Comment: hmm thanx man i got it now, and now m lil curious why i'm getting error at this statement `Type obj = GetType();`

Answer (score 0):

You'd probably have to look at the [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class if you wanted to automatically get that kind of information. Not sure about the performance of using it though...